# Warning in svm-scale libsvm

Tags: svm, libsvm

I'm using `libsvm-3.21` for `epsilon-svr`. I have a training data with so many non zeros (sparse format). When I use `svm-scale` to scale the features into the range [0, 1], I'm getting this warning

```
WARNING: original #nonzeros 503981
       > new      #nonzeros 6450944
If feature values are non-negative and sparse, use -l 0 rather than the default -l -1
```

Should I ignore this warning, does this affect my predictions ?

Answer (score 1):

Sparse inputs can be processed more efficiently. So if you can scale your data in a way as to preserve the zeros training your model might be quite a bit faster.

And a model that takes less time to train might end up giving you better results since you have more time optimising parameters.